# Getting 403 Forbidden error when creating onlineMeetings

Tags: api, microsoft-graph-api, microsoft-graph-sdks

I tried posting to `/app/onlineMeetings` but I always get 403 Forbidden error (both on NodeJS and C#) samples. I already set the API permissions on the app registration and on the scope. Is there anything else that I need to setup before this will work on my end?

Any help is appreciated. Thanks!

[image]

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow! I strongly recommend reading ["How do I ask a good question?"](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask) for some tips on getting started. Error messages are not very helpful on their own. Please add the scopes you've requested, the access token you received back, and a code sample showing how you're calling the API.

Comment: The actual error message (non-screenshot) would also be helpful

Comment: Hi Marc, that is the actual error logs that I got. That's why its hard to trace it down because the error message is lacking in details.

Comment: Yes, but I can't cut paste a screenshot not does that tell me how you're _call_ the API. All I know is you got a 403. If that is all I have to go on, all I can tell you is that you have the wrong permission scopes; which I understand is just as unhelpful to you as a screenshot and no code sample is to me :)

Answer (score 2):

The API `/app/onlinemeetings` is beta API that has been deprecated and is replaced by `/communications/onlinemeetings`.  I recommend trying that instead.

Comment: Hi @Darrel, I already tried it. Same error. Can you point me to any docs/resources about the change? Thanks

Comment: @ekaj_03 The docs update is here https://github.com/microsoftgraph/microsoft-graph-docs/pull/5699

Comment: @Darrell - Thanks for sending that one through. But I think it wasn't yet merged to the main repo. I was already able to call the api via the `/app` endpoint. But I will keep an eye into the updates. Thanks! :)

Comment: hi @ekaj_03 
Do we required Cloud-Video-Interop license for createing Online Meeting?

Comment: @PARAGDESHMUKH you don't need any license to create an online meeting. You just need the app permissions as online meeting endpoint is not supported in in delegate permissions.

Answer (score 0):

I was able to make it work. I didn't realize on the first try that I need to have the application permission level to able to use `onlineMeetings` endpoint. I was just following their NodeJS tutorial that doesn't cover endpoints that need application permissions.

Comment: Dear Jake, I have been stucked for weeks now, can you please share your code snippet for creating onliine meetings and the neccesary settings in AAD

Answer (score 0):

Your problem probably is when you are going to get the access token for your application. If you are using common as tenant id, first you have to do is use your tenant id instead of common word, as explain [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/59276045/solved-getting-forbidden-when-try-to-create-an-online-meeting-using-microsoft-g).